# Is it safe to access the hard drive via many different GCD queues?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, grand-central-dispatch

Is it safe? For instance, if I create a bunch of different GCD queues that each compress (tar cvzf) some files, am I doing something wrong? Will the hard drive be destroyed?

Or does the system properly take care of such things?

Comment: I have my reservations about Apple, but I think even they can manage to write an API that has no risk of hard-drive destruction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take something that is normally IO limited, such as `tar`, and run a bunch of copies in GCD,

1. It will run more slowly because you are throwing more CPU at an IO-bound task, meaning the IO will be more scattered and there will be more of it at the same time,
2. No more than `N` tasks will run at a time, which is the point of GCD, so "a billion queue entries" and "ten queue entries" give you the same thing if you have less than 10 threads,
3. Your hard drive will be fine.

Comment: Not quite right;  the reality is more subtle and can lead to much worse performance for non-obvious reasons.

Answer (score 5):

Dietrich's answer is correct save for one detail (that is completely non-obvious).

If you were to spin off, say, 100 asynchronous `tar` executions via GCD, you'd quickly find that you have 100 threads running in your application (which would also be dead slow due to gross abuse of the I/O subsystem).

In a fully asynchronous concurrent system with queues, there is no way to know if a particular unit of work is blocked because it is waiting for a system resource or waiting for some other enqueued unit of work.  Therefore, anytime anything blocks, you pretty much have to spin up another thread and consume another unit of work or risk locking up the application.

In such a case, the "obvious" solution is to wait a bit when a unit of work blocks before spinning up another thread to de-queue and process another unit of work with the hope that the first unit of work "unblocks" and continues processing.

Doing so, though, would mean that any asynchronous concurrent system with interaction between units of work -- a common case -- would be so slow as to be useless.

Far more effective is to limit the # of units of work that are enqueued in the global asynchronous queues at any one time.   A GCD semaphore makes this quite easy;  you have a single serial queue into which all units of work are enqueued.  Every time you dequeue a unit of work, you increment the semaphore.  Every time a unit of work is completed, you decrement the semaphore.   As long as the semaphore is below some maximum value (say, 4), then you enqueue a new unit of work.

Comment: Without knowing every last dependency between any two units of work, there is no way for GCD to know that the enqueued B is or isn't required to complete the now-blocking A.

Answer (score 3):

Even though this question was asked back in May, it's still worth noting that GCD has now provided I/O primitives with the release of 10.7 (OS X Lion).  See the man pages for dispatch_read and dispatch_io_create for examples on how to do efficient I/O with the new APIs.  They are smart enough to properly schedule I/O against a single disk (or multiple disks) with knowledge of how much concurrency is, or is not, possible in the actual I/O requests.